# How to add "extract here" or "p7zip" menu item? (Gnome3, Nemo)

Tags: fedora, zip, gnome3

I'm using Fedora 20 with Gnome3 and Nemo.

I installed p7zip but I don't see a p7zip or "extract here" item when right-clicking on a .zip

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you install the nemo-fileroller package?

That fixed it for me, but I had to log out and back in again first.

Comment: It worked, thanks! Instead of relogging I did `killall nemo`.